# Run outlook rule on all mailboxes (Accounts)?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, rules

I have more than 10 email accounts all opened in outlook 2016, I have some rule to collect all emails with specific subject to a folder in on of my mail accounts, the problem here that I have to select every single mailbox then run the rule from it, is their any way to run rule on all mailboxes (accounts) at once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching the internet, I found the following VBA code that can run rule or rules on all email accounts, the code is below:

```
Sub RunRulesSecondary()

Dim oStores As Outlook.Stores
Dim oStore As Outlook.Store

Dim olRules As Outlook.Rules
Dim myRule As Outlook.Rule
Dim olRuleNames() As Variant
Dim name As Variant

' Enter the names of the rules you want to run
olRuleNames = Array("Rule1")

Set oStores = Application.Session.Stores
For Each oStore In oStores
On Error Resume Next

' use the display name as it appears in the navigation pane
If oStore.DisplayName <> "email@domain.ddns.net" Then

Set olRules = oStore.GetRules()

For Each name In olRuleNames()

    For Each myRule In olRules
       Debug.Print "myrule " & myRule

     If myRule.name = name Then

' inbox belonging to oStore
' need GetfolderPath functionhttp://slipstick.me/4eb2l
        myRule.Execute ShowProgress:=True, Folder:=GetFolderPath(oStore.DisplayName & "\Inbox")

' current folder
'      myRule.Execute ShowProgress:=True, Folder:=Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder

       End If
    Next
Next

End If
Next
End Sub

Function GetFolderPath(ByVal FolderPath As String) As Outlook.Folder
    Dim oFolder As Outlook.Folder
    Dim FoldersArray As Variant
    Dim i As Integer

    On Error GoTo GetFolderPath_Error
    If Left(FolderPath, 2) = "\\" Then
        FolderPath = Right(FolderPath, Len(FolderPath) - 2)
    End If
    'Convert folderpath to array
    FoldersArray = Split(FolderPath, "\")
    Set oFolder = Application.Session.Folders.Item(FoldersArray(0))
    If Not oFolder Is Nothing Then
        For i = 1 To UBound(FoldersArray, 1)
            Dim SubFolders As Outlook.Folders
            Set SubFolders = oFolder.Folders
            Set oFolder = SubFolders.Item(FoldersArray(i))
            If oFolder Is Nothing Then
                Set GetFolderPath = Nothing
            End If
        Next
    End If
    'Return the oFolder
    Set GetFolderPath = oFolder
    Exit Function

GetFolderPath_Error:
    Set GetFolderPath = Nothing
    Exit Function
End Function
```

the email account email@domain, is the folder where I collect all emails by a specific rule.